# Таблица не форматируется по ширине текста в LATEX

Tags: table, таблицы, latex

Необходимо сделать таблицу, которая должна в автоматическом режиме форматироваться по ширине страницы.
Пытаюсь сделать через longtable но не понимаю где должен указать параметр автоматического подбора ширины. Сейчас текст вылезает за границы.

```
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Вид исследования &
  Среднее   количество день &
  Среднее   количество в* &
  Комментарий \\ \hline
\endhead
%
Компьютерная   томография (КТ) – исследования &
  5 пациентов /аппарат &
  30 пациентов   /аппарат &
  Есть возможности   для увеличения количества пациентов, которым проводится исследование. Сильная   сторона, что всем онкологическим пациентам проводятся исследования с в/в   контрастированием \\ \hline
Компьютерная   томография – описание &
  12 зон/врача &
  25 зон/врача &
  Возможно   увеличение количества описываемых зон и количества исследований, необходимо   дополнительно закупить один терминал для врача-специалиста. \\ \hline
Гастроскопия &
  25 пациентов &
  24 пациента &
  Гастроскопия   проводится в достаточных объемах, с максимальной нагрузкой на врачей-специалистов   и текущее оборудование. Необходимо провести ремонт или замену вышедших из   строя гастроскопов (2 шт.). \\ \hline
Колоноскопия &
  3 &
  10 &
  Есть возможности   увеличить количество проводимых колоноскопий. По опыту НМИЦ в среднем количество   исследований, которые можно выполнять в течение рабочего дня приближаются к   8-10 случаям с учетом работы 3 колоноскопии. \\ \hline
Маммография &
  20 пациентов &
  12 &
  В медицинской   организации установлен аналоговый маммограф без оцифровщика. Специалисты   описывают исследования не применяя современные методики типа BI-RADS, что затрудняет   проведение стандартизации протоколов исследований. \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Удалось сделать только через жестко заданный размер ячейки, но это не всегда удобно

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{7cm}}
\hline
Вид исследования & Среднее количество день & Среднее количество* & Комментарий\\
\hline
Компьютерная томография (КТ) – исследования & 5 пациентов /аппарат  & 30 пациентов /аппарат &  Есть возможности для увеличения количества пациентов, которым проводится исследование. Сильная сторона, что всем онкологическим пациентам проводятся исследования с в/в контрастированием \\
\hline
Компьютерная томография – описание & 12 зон/врача & 25 зон/врача & Возможно увеличение количества описываемых зон и количества исследований, необходимо дополнительно закупить один терминал для врача-специалиста.\\
\hline
Гастроскопия & 25 пациентов & 24 пациента & Гастроскопия проводится в достаточных объемах, с максимальной нагрузкой на врачей-специалистов и текущее оборудование. Необходимо провести ремонт или замену вышедших из строя гастроскопов (2 шт.).\\
\hline
Колоноскопия & 3 пациента & 10 пациентов & Есть возможности увеличить количество проводимых колоноскопий. По опыту НМИЦ в среднем количество исследований, которые можно выполнять в течение рабочего дня приближаются к 8-10 случаям с учетом работы 3 колоноскопии.\\
\hline
Маммография & 20 пациентов & 25 пациентов & В медицинской организации установлен аналоговый маммограф без оцифровщика. Специалисты описывают исследования не применяя современные методики типа BI-RADS, что затрудняет проведение стандартизации протоколов исследований.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

`longtable` не умеет ставить ограничение на ширину таблицы, если только не задать его вручную каждому столбцу.

В Вашем случае подойдёт пакет `xltabular` - это смесь `longtable` и `tabularx` (в последнем окружении можно указать максимальную ширину таблицы и указать столбец, который будет подстраиваться под остальные).

Ваш пример перекроить не могу, потому что не знаю, как должен выглядеть результат + неизвестны остальные параметры документа. Поэтому просто оставлю ссылки на документацию к вышеуказанным пакетам:

tabularx: https://mirrors.mi-ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf

xltabular: https://mirrors.mi-ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xltabular/xltabular-doc.pdf